# How to fix context dict in CBV view in django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates, django-views

I have this View and get context data method
[View](https://github.com/doubledare704/depositICS/blob/caccb9a1ea1edd6db3d642c968c8b6e226283e06/core/views.py#L97)
In the end of view's code i put difference dict into context key.Then i try to output all data into template, but last 3 fields are empty.
[image]
Here is template code: [Template for view](https://github.com/doubledare704/depositICS/blob/caccb9a1ea1edd6db3d642c968c8b6e226283e06/templates/core/analysis.html#L37).
In the end of view I print difference in.
[Console prints](https://github.com/doubledare704/depositICS/blob/caccb9a1ea1edd6db3d642c968c8b6e226283e06/core/views.py#L144)
It gives me all data I need.

```
[{'depos': Decimal('400000.00'), 'df': Decimal('-4600000.00'), 'pr': Decimal('-38722782.00'), 'creds': Decimal('5000000.00'), 'date': (2016, 3), 'dc': 'Створити акційні пропозиції, переглядати або створити депозитні програми'}, 
{'depos': Decimal('450776.00'), 'df': Decimal('-33783479.00'), 'pr': Decimal('-38672006.00'), 'creds': Decimal('34234255.00'), 'date': (2016, 2), 'dc': 'Створити акційні пропозиції, переглядати або створити депозитні програми'}, 
{'depos': Decimal('3473400.00'), 'df': Decimal('2973399.98'), 'pr': Decimal('-35649382.00'), 'creds': Decimal('500000.02'), 'date': (2016, 4), 'dc': 'Слід знижувати відсоткові ставки в депозитних програмах'}]
```

I'd like to output all fields from that dict. How to fix this issue in template/view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In last four statements you are not using `dif` but `difs`:

```
{% for dif in difs %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ dif.depos }}</td>
        <td>{{ dif.creds }}</td>
        <td>{{ dif.date }}{{ difs.df }}</td>   <--- should be dif.df
        <td>{{ difs.df }}</td>                 <--- should be dif.df 
        <td>{{ difs.dc }}</td>                 <--- should be dif.dc 
        <td>{{ difs.pr }}</td>                 <--- should be dif.pr
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It really is, I didn't catched that kids' mistake(

Comment: hold on, more 15 secs and i do it)